# nodejs fs.writeFile to sysfs (/sys) doesn't seem to work

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, kernel-module, sysfs, 1wire

I'm using the [w1_therm](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/w1/slaves/w1_therm.rst) kernel module to read temperature of a few DS18B20 temperature sensors on a Raspberry Pi 4. This works well by just reading the `temperature` files in `/sys/bus/w1/devices/<ROM>`.

Since I have quite a few sensors I want to make use of the bulk temperature conversion feature (see linked docs above). This can be triggered by writing `trigger` to `/sys/bus/w1/devices/w1_bus_master1/therm_bulk_read`. This write will take a bit over 750ms (that is how long the temperature conversion takes for full precision on DS18B20s). The temperature reads after that are just reading from the fs and don't trigger another conversion, meaning they are very fast.

Now to the problem: If I manually write using `echo trigger > /sys/bus/w1/devices/w1_bus_master1/therm_bulk_read` everything works, but if I try to do this from node js (v18.17.1) using `await writeFile(...)` (where `writeFile` is imported from `fs/promises`) the write takes only ~20ms (doesn't throw) and the following temperature reads are slow, meaning the bulk trigger didn't work. I tried opening the file in nodejs, writing and then calling `sync()` on the file descriptor to no avail.
The node process has permission to write to that file.

I tried `spawn`ing a process form node that just `echo`s to the file as a debugging step and that works perfectly fine.

Any ideas why `writeFile` doesn't work are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

‍♂️ As usual, you try to find a solution for hours and the second you ask the question you find it.
I forgot to add a new line when writing to the file, i.e. `writeFile(path, 'trigger\n')`. `echo` does that by default.

Comment: Congrats, you actually found a bug (and I looked thru w1 subsystem code, it's old and ugly, one can easily create 50+ cleanup patches for it!) in the kernel code: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/w1/slaves/w1_therm.c#L1948. This `if` with followed up `if (!strncmp)` (so, both conditionals) have to be replaced with a single `if (sysfs_streq(...))`. With that it wouldn't require, but allow to still use, bogus `\n`. You may create a patch and send to the kernel mailing list.